# React Context outside a React Component or alternatives

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have different endpoints defined in a file called endpoints.ts. Each of those endpoints receive a token (which is used later in Authentication header).

*endpoints.ts*

```
const getAllObjects = (token) => fetch(...);
const getSingleObject = (id, token) => fetch(...);
```

***The problem***

Every time I use call one of those endpoints from a React component, I have to pass the token (which is saved in React context) like this:

```
const user = await getSingleObject(id, context.user.token);
```

I find that very repetitive since I have multiple requests through my application.

***What I have tried so far***

I tried to simplify endpoints.ts by making it have access to React Context. I wanted to do something like this:

```
const context = useContext(context);
const token = context.user.token

const getAllObjects = () => fetch(...);
const getSingleObject = (id) => fetch(...);
```

However, that is not allowed because edpoints.ts does not have a React component so, it is not a valid Consumer for React Context.

Can you suggest another solution?

Comment: Write a custom hook that exposes the context you need

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite your `endpoints.ts` to a custom hook using `useContext`:

```
const getAllObjects = () => fetch();

const useFetchFunctions = () => {
  const context = useContext(context);
  const token = context.user.token;

  // Can be memoized by token value using React.useCallback
  const getSingleObject = (id) => fetch(id, token);
  return { getSingleObject, getAllObjects };
};
```

And use it within context consumers (so `useContext` will be valid).

Comment: Ok thank you. I will go ahead with this approach.

One doubt: Why is the reason that make me able to access the context with this approach  even though useFetchFunctions is not a consumer of <Context.Provider>?
Is the reason the fact that the keyword 'use' is ahead of 'FetchFunctions'?

Comment: The consumer is the **component** using the hook, the component itself has to be a child of Context provider - that's why `useContext` will work only in consumers as mentioned.

Comment: The `use` prefix is **ONLY** used for linting warnings (and recommended pattern to notify this function is a custom hook).